# На что выделяются адреса до 0x00040000 в памяти процесса? Windows

Tags: windows, память, процесс

В памяти процесса, как я понял, адресное пространство, хранящее стеки потоков, загружаемые файлы и т.д., расположено в адресах от 0х00010000 до 0х7FFEFFFF в 32-битной Windows. В [Данной](http://datadump.ru/process-address-space/) статье это подтверждается, однако, ниже при более подробном разборе данного блока адресов сказано, что минимальный адрес, в который загружается первая библиотека - это 0х00040000. Отсюда вопрос: куда девается пространство от 0х00010000 до 0х0003FFFF?

Comment: Откройте утилиту типа Virtual Memory Map и посмотрите.

Comment: @user7860670 очень подробный и исчерпывающий ответ, спасибо

Comment: Принадлежащие процессу регионы памяти могут находиться в одном из 3-х основных состояний: COMMIT (используются), RESERVE (зарезервированы, но не используются) и FREE (свободны). Так-что память никуда не девается, а просто свободна. Функция Win32-API `VirtualQuery()` перечисляет все регионы памяти, возвращая их состояние и флаги защиты, а `VirtualAlloc()` может выделить регион из свободного участка.