# Есть ли в памяти процесса специальный сегмент, выделенный под динамическую память? С++

Tags: c++, windows, память, процесс

Если я все правильно понимаю, то стек - это заранее выделенный кусок памяти. Поэтому при появлении новых переменных в стеке они записываются и считываются быстро. А что насчет динамической памяти? Правильно ли я понимаю, что на уровне адресного пространства куча не имеет какого-то выделенного сегмента и под "кучей" подразумевается все остальное свободное адресное пространство, которое выделяется по мере необходимости в рантайме? И при этом выделяется не сразу кусок памяти на все, как стек, а только под конкретную переменную?

Или же у нас при запросе на выделение памяти в куче выделяется страница памяти и все переменные, созданные при помощи `new` пишутся и читаются оттуда, а когда память на странице кончается, то выделяется еще одна?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344490/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be-0x00040000-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-windows#comment2381497_1344490

Comment: Обычно в linker script (это скрипт для линкера, который из объектников и библиотек собирает загружаемый модуль) между bss (статические переменные) и стеком размещают сегмент heap размером несколько мегабайт. Из этой памяти первоначально malloc и выдает запрашиваемую память. Если ее не хватает (или одноразовый запрос памяти достаточно большой), то у ОС запрашивется дополнительная память. Но не одна страница, конечно, а намного больше. Это не означает, что ко всем выделенным виртуальным страницам будут сразу приписаны физические. Такое связывание обычно откладывается до первого обращения к ней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если я все правильно понимаю, то стек - это заранее выделенный кусок памяти.

Примерно так, но следует отметить:

1. В многопоточном приложении каждый поток имеет собственный стек. Иногда требуется корректировать размеры этих стеков;
2. При использовании виртуальной памяти, что сейчас чаще всего применяется, выделение куска адресного пространства приложением и отведение ОС реальной памяти под страницы этого адресного пространства - это разные операции. В частности, если настроить размер стека 100 Мб, то 100 Мб адресного пространства будет отведено сразу, а реальные 100 Мб будут выделены приложению не сразу, а постепенно.

> И при этом выделяется не сразу кусок памяти на все, как стек, а только под конкретную переменную?

Менеджеры памяти могут иметь разные алгоритмы. Обычно, у менеджера есть пул свободных страниц, под которые уже выделено адресное пространство. По возможности, new/malloc() выделяет память из него, а delete/free() возвращает память в него, но при нехватке или избытке менеджер памяти запрашивает у ОС дополнительное адресное пространство или возвращает излишки.

Пулов может быть несколько, для разных размеров, с целью уменьшения фрагментации, или для разных потоков многопоточного приложения, с целью уменьшения интерференции кэш и взаимных блокировок.

Comment: То есть получается, что память выделяется все таки минимум страницами, а не побайтово для каждой переменной?

Comment: @ComeInRage , обычно, побайтовое выделение памяти, как адресного пространства, так и реальной памяти, требует слишком много ресурсов. Однако, есть менеджеры памяти для отладки, которые для каждого new/malloc() выделяют страницу с запретом чтения/записи, а потом страницу(-ы) ровно необходимой длины (остальная часть последней страницы тоже с запретом чтения/записи).

Comment: @ComeInRage P.S. Да, память под внешние и статические переменные обычно происходит одним куском при загрузке приложения или библиотек.